# How can we load a CSV file into JupyterLab using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I couldn't find a straightforward way to run d3 in JupyterLab, but when I load it this way:

```html
%%html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

This works:

```js
%%javascript
d3.select(element)
    .append("text")
    .text("Hello World!");
```

`Hello World!`

Now I am trying to load a CSV file like this one:

```
Name,Count
A,10
B,15
C,14
```

To do so, I run this:

```js
%%javascript
d3.csv("df.csv", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This does not work and output is something like this:
[image]

What's the correct way to load CSV into JupyterLab using d3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a static file so in order to load it you need to use an endpoint which serves files as raw text/blobs, which is `files/`. It requires a path relative to root of the jupyter server (this is the directory where you start JupyterLab from). For example, if you have the `df.csv` in the root directory and your URL for JupyterLab looks like:

```
http://localhost:8889/lab/tree/Untitled.ipynb
```

you want to use:

```
http://localhost:8888/files/df.csv
```